# Javascript for loop not doing expected behavior in its last loop

Tags: javascript, loops

the code below is inside a function that is triggered every time an image is clicked. Every that function runs, it will be inserting the word "show" to the class name of specific elements and removing it from others.

When the last item of the array labelsFilterDiv ( index 83) is the one with the word "show" in its class name,  the function enters the second `if statement` ( `if (labelsFilterDiv[q].className.indexOf(filterWord) > -1)`) but not the
`else if` statement `else if (q === labelsFilterDiv.length - 1)`

I would appreciate any feedback to understand why. Thanks.

```
let labelsFilterDiv = document.querySelectorAll(".filterDiv"); // Removed ".div" from the selector 

let labelsShown = [];


for (var i = 0; i < labelsFilterDiv.length; i++) {


  if (labelsFilterDiv[i].className.indexOf("show") > -1) {

            labelsShown.push(element);
            var filterWord = displayedLabeldiv.className.split(" ")[1];

            let labelsWithFilterWordIndividualArray = []

            for (let q = 0; q < labelsFilterDiv.length; q++) {
     

                if (labelsFilterDiv[q].className.indexOf(filterWord) > -1) { // this will be checked 84 times, from 0 to 83. 

                     labelsWithFilterWordIndividualArray.push(labelsFilterDiv[q]);

      
                } else if (q === labelsFilterDiv.length - 1) { 

                       
                     labelsWithFilterWord.push(labelsWithFilterWordIndividualArray);

                  }


          }

    }

}
```

Comment: If you want the `else if` to take precedence over the `if` then swap their order so the `else if` becomes the `if` and the `if` becomes the `else if`.

Comment: Only one path will be executed in an `if/else if/else` chain, not multiple.

Comment: When you say "with the word show in its class name" do you mean that it might have a class like "showfirst" (show is **in** - is a _part_ of - the class name) or do you mean the element has a class named (exactly) "show" but could have other classes too, like `<div class="show bright">` ? I'm thinking you may want to be using [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) instead of `className`. If you're splitting className on space, well that's really more than one class, and classList works with multiple classes on a single element. Add some sample HTML for us.

Comment: Thanks so much you all three!  All your comments allowed me to find the right answer. I created two different if statements

Comment: You're welcome. You should post an answer to your own question with the solution, otherwise there's no point to your question being here and you should delete it, since this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

```
for (let q = 0; q < labelsFilterDiv.length; q++) {

     if (labelsFilterDiv[q].className.indexOf(filterWord) > -1) { 
            labelsWithFilterWordIndividualArray.push(labelsFilterDiv[q]); 
     }


      if (q === labelsFilterDiv.length - 1) { 
            labelsWithFilterWord.push(labelsWithFilterWordIndividualArray);
      }

 }
```